ЧПУ .htaccess. Не открываются страницы
Не открываются URL-ссылки, только чпу в адресной строке.
Алиасы и url хранятся в db.
Базовый htaccess

   
    RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?%{QUERY_STRING}
    

URL
/?view=section&id=1
/?view=article&id=1
/?view=reg

В RewriteRule $1 хранится алиас, но где статический URL непонятно

Не очень понятно в сем именно проблема. Было бы полезно в вопросе указать ссылки которые открываются в браузере и к каокму скрипту для этого должно быть обращение.

Зта ссылка без скрипта
http://demo/?view=section&id=1
эта с заменой
http://demo/string-functions
И код с распарсеным алиасом.
$vars = parse_url($this->sef->getSefAlias($alias));
parse_str($vars["query"], $vars);
$vars["view"]  //article/section
$vars["id"] //id
Пытался зти значения внести в htaccess, как вариант, но никак.

Попробуйте вот так:

    # Включить RewriteEngine и резолвить симлинки
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteBase /
    
    # Пропускать существующие файлы и папки
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    
    # Обрабатываем сначала статичные URL
    # три примера:
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=section&id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?view=section&id=%1 [L]
    
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=article&id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?view=article&id=%1 [L]
    
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=reg$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?view=reg [L]
    
    # Уже после обрабатываем ЧПУ
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?alias=$1 [L,QSA]


Вот как это работает:

Сначала обрабатываются статические URL:


Когда приходит запрос вида /?view=section&id=1, он обрабатывается первым блоком правил

%1 содержит значение из первой круглой скобки в RewriteCond



Затем обрабатываются ЧПУ:


Если URL не соответствует статическим шаблонам, срабатывает последнее правило
$1 содержит алиас из URL
Флаг QSA (Query String Append) позволяет добавлять дополнительные параметры


В PHP можно получить:


    // Для статических URL
    $view = $_GET['view'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
        
    // Для ЧПУ
    $alias = $_GET['alias'];



Спасибо. Но выводит 404
С %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=section&id=([0-9]+)$
что-то не так.
get-URL глушится что ли
Или шаблон не верный
id=([0-9]+)$  на $_GET["id"] не реагирует.

Вообще, написано верно. Странно. Но ладно. Попробуйте заменить эти строки на
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?view=section&id=([0-9]+) [NC] и
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L].

То есть, заменить %{QUERY_STRING} на %{THE_REQUEST}. Убрать $ в конце шаблона. В RewriteRule оставляем GET-параметры как есть, они автоматически передаются в PHP

@shamilshakirov попробуйте должно сработать
